# 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

why my code is showing this error as my whole code is correct?

> 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_list_or_404
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm

def update_task(request, pk):
    up_task = get_list_or_404(Task, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        up_form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=up_task)
        if up_form.is_valid():
            up_form.save()
            return redirect('tasks')
    else:
        up_form = TaskForm(instance=up_task)

    context = {
        'update_task_form': up_form
    }
    return render(request, 'task/update_task.html', context)
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.tasks, name='tasks'),
    path('task/<str:pk>/update/', views.update_task, name='update_task'),
]
```

*Error*

> Internal Server Error: /task/3/update/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner response = get_response(request)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\PycharmProject\todoapp\todoapp\task\views.py", line 31, in update_task
> up_form = TaskForm(instance=up_task)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 294, in **init**
> object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 85, in model_to_dict
> opts = instance._meta
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
> [04/Oct/2020 09:06:27] "GET /task/3/update/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71974
> Internal Server Error: /task/3/update/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\PycharmProject\todoapp\todoapp\task\views.py", line 31, in update_task
> up_form = TaskForm(instance=up_task)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 294, in **init**
> object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
> File "C:\Users\Royal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 85, in model_to_dict
> opts = instance._meta
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`get_object_or_404`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of `get_list_or_404`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# and in your view
up_task = get_object_or_404(Task, id=pk)
```

### Update

Update your template as,

```
<form action="{% url 'tasks' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ update_task_form }}
</form>
<a type="submit" href="">Update</a>
```

Comment: Reverse for 'update_task' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['task/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/update/$']

Comment: this is my template

Comment: <form action="{% url 'update_task' update_task_form.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

   {{ update_task_form }}

</form>
<a type="submit" href="">Update</a>

Comment: it worked but not updating. means there is no link to update the form